# Using streams and lambda expressions to replace a nested for loop to enter into a nested list

Tags: java, list, lambda, nested, java-stream

hello so i have a `List<List<RGBpixel> photo`  and i want to get the values out of this nested list and put in to `List<List<GrayscalePixel>> grayPhoto` while i'm putting these in i need to use my methode `.convertToGrayscale` on the `RBGpixel`s inside the first nested list. the outer list is filled up with the rows of the picture i'm trying to read, so this will make rows and colums of the pixels of the picture.

```
for (int i = 0; i < photo.size(); i++) {                                                                             
   List<GrayscalePixel> row = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int j = 0; j < photo.get(0).size(); j++) {
      row.add(photo.get(i).get(j).convertToGrayscale());                        
   }
   grayPhoto.add(row);
}
```

How would I convert this so it uses streams and lambda

`photo.forEach(r -> r.forEach(e-> row.add(e.convertToGrayscale())));`

this was my attempt at it but it does not work because i cant find a way to make it put the row in the nested list once one it reaches a point where the amount of values is equal to the size of the picture like i did using the for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly translating your for loops to `forEach`, look at what your for loops are doing on a higher level of abstraction. They are transforming each element of your lists to another element. Whenever you see transformations like this, `map` is what you should call.

```
List<List<GrayscalePixel>> grayscalePhoto = 
    photo.stream().map(x ->
        x.stream().map(RGBpixel::convertToGrayscale).collect(Collectors.toList())
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Naman a flat map would produce a 1D list though, wouldn’t it?